# How can I make my system usable after modifying /usr/share/icons's permissions?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

I'm running a duel boot/partition machine with Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. On Ubuntu OS, I wanted to change the permissions in one of my directories so could extract files into that directory. In the terminal I entered `chmod -R 777 /usr/share/icons` which gives the owner, group, global read, write, and execute permissions. After I extracted the files into the directory, in the terminal I then entered `chmod -R 644 /usr/share/icons` which I believe gives the owner read and write permissions but the group and global read-only permissions. This was a mistake.

After I entered this command, the entire system froze and some of the icons were missing. I restarted the computer and logged back in but it gave the same problem. The Linux system has become inoperable.

I'm currently on my Windows 7 OS. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, boot from Ubuntu LiveCD, open terminal and run commands:

```
 cd /usr/share/icons
 sudo find -type d chmod +x '{}' ';'
```

This will add 'executable' bit for directories (and you will be able to get listings of that directories).